# After upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 my laptop does not turn on without the power supply

Tags: 12.04, battery

I saw that this questions was previously asked from other version  of ubuntu, and no one seems to have an answer.

How can I fix this?.
How can I check also if is a bettery problem (the battery does not charge anymore also)

PLease!!!

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of several things:

1. Dead charger
2. Dead battery
3. Dead charging circuits within the laptop

Do you have another charger to test with? Does the battery itself have a charging indicator (a number of the Dell batteries have this)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its that simple. I am having the same issue, and i was experiencing the same in Ubuntu 11.10. If the AC is on while booting, ubuntu also shows a charging sign. If however, its un-plugged and re-plugged while ubuntu is running, it does not change back to battery charging mode. 
I have windows 7, and it does work ok on it. So I dont have a battery issue at all.

I think there is no clear solution right now, i hope there will be one soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues, did you manage to fix the issue?

It seems to be an issue with the motherboard, you could try disabling acpi on boot

[How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Also try updating your BIOS