# How do I disable ACPI when booting?

Tags: installation, boot, acpi

When I tried to install Ubuntu from the live CD start menu, the screen became black with just a blinking cursor. I rebooted the PC and I chose the option `acpi=off`. Then the installer started and Ubuntu installed whitout problems.

But when I reboot the PC now after the installation was complete the screen goes black again. I am new in the use of Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/160056/888288
This worked for my case and I no longer get the ACPI error.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please add `acpi=off` to the kernel command line -- it's just slightly different than doing it with the LiveCD:

1. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting up, to get the Grub menu. Use the arrow keys to navigate/highlight the entry you want (usually the first one).

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit that entry, which will show you the details:

   [image]
3. Find the `linux` entry as shown above, use the arrow keys to get to it, and then  press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to get to that line's end (which may be on the next line!). Enter **`acpi=off`** as shown, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.
4. You can make this workaround permanent by:

   - `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
   - Change line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.
   - `sudo update-grub`
   - Reboot and you should no longer have the black screen problem.

See also:

- [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)

Comment: This might be a noob question but are there any potential long term implications to running the system like this?

I only know that ACPI relates to power, could running with ACPI disabled make the fans not work or make the computer fail to realise when the battery is low, for example?

Comment: @AidyJ https://askubuntu.com/questions/858370/is-it-dangerous-to-turn-acpi-off

Answer (score 5):

Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Advanced options` to add `acpi=off` (or any other kernel option) to your GRUB in 1 click. It will also provide a BootInfo summary if you need more help.

[image]

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation

Comment: after disabling acpi, wifi and ethernet are not working and interfaces are not listing at all. I am using MSI GE62 with Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: As Boot-Repair is not an official Ubuntu package, this is a not good solution.

Comment: I don't see how it's not a good solution only because of this. Boot-repair is widely used and doesn't mess things if used with advanced options. The solution shown here is simply a way to add a kernel option, nothing else.