# How to set acpi=off for installation?

Tags: 12.04, installation, acpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit from a USB created in Windows using the recommended software from pendrivelinux. The USB is tested on two laptops and works fine.

The install does not work on my desktop PC, it either hangs with lots of text on the screen, or it just gives me a screen with garbled colors. 
Right now it hangs on "[3.925311] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...", but it hangs on different spots every time I try.

I know that acpi=off will fix this.

On older versions, there used to be a pink screen with the icon of a keyboard, at that screen I could press ESC, and I would then get a long list of languages, I could choose English, and then I would get options for setting acpi=off, then install without any problems. This new install menu does not have those options.

The (now black and white) "Installer boot menu"'s advanced options is blank. There simply are no advanced options.
If I go to help, then press F6, I get to a help screen describing the different boot parameters. I see examples of writing "Install acpi=off" 
However, writing "install acpi=off" it gives an error saying "could not find kernel image: install".

How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 with acpi=off?

(Oh, btw, nothing happens if I press F6 in the "Installer boot menu")

Comment: FINALLY found the answer. It is not entirely the same as- but similar to what you find in this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have burned the wrong CD image, perhaps the one for servers. The current Precise CDs for i386 Desktop have the pink/purple screen and allow you to select the language, and then go through the F6 option to set kernel options for booting the installation system--just as you described.