# Ubuntu 12.10 stuck on black screen with a lot of text

Tags: installation, 12.10, kernel

I put Ubuntu 12.10 x64 installation on my USB using universal USB installer. Then, I reboot the computer and select to boot from the USB. I get the keyboard logo, and I press space and select language. Then, I press <kbd>f6</kbd> for more options and select "nomodeset". I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and waited for half a minute. I got this:

[image: Kernel panic]

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make it work?

Note: I have a HP Pavilion g7 1303 which currently has Windows 8 installed (Wasn't preinstalled, the laptop's older than Windows 8).

Comment: Your screenshot is not showing a kernel panic. Do you mean that the boot process hangs at this point?

Comment: @JenniferWilson yes, That's what I mean. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Until someone who knows more about it comes and help, try to [disable acpi when booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting) since it seems to be a frequent cause of boot issues.

Comment: @jenniferwilson I tried to disable acpi and got the following screen:
http://shrani.si/f/39/6I/3WE3tszs/p240313140301.jpg

Comment: Is there a recovery mode when booting on USB? What is the exact model name 1303? Something like "1303er". It looks like [Ubuntu 12.04 supports the Pavilion g7](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201209-11634/) (not sure about variations), so you might want to try that instead. By the way, I noticed a few of your questions: congrats on trying hard to install Ubuntu!

Comment: @jenniferwilson I do not know, there are just two, I have the one with the bigger screen. I already have Ubuntu 12.04 and it works, but I really want to try 12.10 - upgrading failed so I thought of a clean install. There isn't a recovery mode when booting on USB.

Comment: The solution is simple: do not use `nomodeset`. What did you **expect** using `nomodeset`?

Comment: @Private If I don't use nomodeset, I get a empty black screen, this is an issue with graphics

Answer (score 1):

zdravo matej, try to press CTRL+ALT+F1 or any other to F6, and than simply login as you login in normal gui mode, with your username. then when you are logged in, try to run command:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

and let me know if helped. if not, jebiga moramo naci drugo resenje :D

Comment: zdravo Dimitris I haven't installed Ubuntu, this happens when I try to install Ubuntu, so I canot login with my username and password because I don't have an username and a password.

Comment: do you install trough wubi or real version? give me info what you really get? try to reinstall from your cd or usb. there is lot of possibilities. you have mayeb 32bit computer, and 64bit ubuntu version, graphic card non compatibile, your disk is maybe still NTFS formated (only windows can use it ). tell me what you really done during instalation i didnt understood, you can tell me in croatian too if you want ( or bosnian, serbian dont know whats your language).

Comment: I install the normal version, I tried to reinstall, I have a 64 bit computer and 64 bit Ubuntu version, graphics card is not compatible but it's fixed with nomodeset, I haven't even came to installation, I just put my USB into the computer and turn it on, I haven't even come to the partition. (my language is Slovenian).

Comment: look, if you run ubuntu desktop from usb, first boot from it, and instead of install just run it first. than open disk utility from dash menu, format your hard disk as Ext4 and completely empty it. then reboot and run ubuntu from usb dont select install directly, i had same problerm with it. when you run ubuntu on desktop you have install ubuntu, even on launcher. first connect to internet, select install 3rd party whatever it was, and not select updates during installation. update and upgrade after instalation is fully completed. let me know about results.

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages), so reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` package doesn't actually reinstall any software. Reinstalling or installing it *will* have the effect of causing any missing dependencies to be installed (not reinstalled). Is that your intention? If so, I recommend expanding your answer (by *editing* it) to explain what you intend to accomplish by running that command. Also, adding information you've provided in comments may improve the answer and make it a better resource for others with a similar problem.

Comment: @MatejKranjec While it seems unlikely (to me) that the *specific* command given in this answer will fix the problem, please note that [virtual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) work in a live environment just like in an installed system. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1. It's a live environment, so you don't even have to log in. Alt+F7 returns to the GUI.

Comment: I cannot boot to desktop because I get that screen. I also do not want to format my whole disk because I have Windows 8 on. I successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 but failed when trying to install 12.10.