# Is this a misreading, or should I be concerned? lm-sensors output

Tags: temperature

I have an AMD quad (A10) desktop, which has the following output from sensors:

```
$ sensors
f71808a-isa-0600
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:        +3.28 V  
in1:          +0.00 V  
in2:          +0.00 V  
in3:          +0.00 V  
3VSB:         +3.28 V  
Vbat:         +3.46 V  
fan1:         888 RPM
fan2:         991 RPM
fan3:           0 RPM  ALARM
temp1:       +231.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, hyst = +81.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +96.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +35.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, hyst = +81.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +96.0°C)  sensor = transistor
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +31.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +69.0°C)
```

That temp1 reading is so high it looks wrong. It has been like that for a while, and the computer still works. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things will start to melt when you go over 140°C. Things both in and around the CPU. 231°C is actually beyond the ignition temperature of a lot of plastic components that may be in your computer. That's a bad situation.

Given your desktop hasn't reduced itself to a flaming puddle (yet) I'm going to say this is almost certainly a bug in lm-sensors or the I²C driver.

---

You're not the only person to have run into their f71808a-isa-0600 I²C chip reporting exactly 231.0°C, [here's another](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1187732). They were having stability issues and found that [disabling ACPI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting) helped.

If you aren't experiencing any actual issues (and there isn't a dead fan) I'd just leave it but you may get value from reporting this as a bug. I'm not exactly sure who's responsible here. Start with the [lm-sensors developers](http://lm-sensors.org/) and see if you get kicked up to the kernel developers.