# Unable to boot Live CD with hard drive attached

Tags: live-cd, initramfs, busybox

I am attempting to fix an OS drive that had some problems after installing updates. The hard drive is currently not bootable. My main goal right now is just to get some data off this drive.

I have a live CD which I am able to boot from when the hard drive is not attached. When I attach the hard drive however I get an error message **after** clicking "Try Ubunutu before installing".

The error message looks like this:

```
[    14.071718] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[    24.087575] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-8ubunutu1) built-in shell (ash)

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Any thoughts on how I can get into this hard drive or what is keeping the Live CD from booting properly when the hard drive is connected?

Comment: Could you put the hard drive in an external USB enclosure then plug the drive in after "Try Ubuntu" is booted up?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have one, but if I don't find any other ideas I will go get one.

Comment: Also, you might need to go to your BIOS and change the SATA controller from IDE to AHCI.

Comment: Already done. Thank you for the idea though.

Comment: Most BIOSes support SATA hot-unplugging/hot-plugging, check if that's the case for your BIOS

Comment: It does and I tried plugging in the drive once already booted but it did not show up under `/dev` or `sudo fdisk -l`. I had this working earlier this morning. I would say it seems like the drive has died, but if that was the case I would think it wouldn't affect the Live CD booting.

Comment: I did a little further searching and found the bug they refer to for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/543875  but it lead to http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nforce/1.0-0306/KnownProblems.html which basically recommends disabling ACPI in BIOS.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: It worked, and the drive showed up! Thank you very much. You should submit this as an answer so I can accept it. Only difference is I had to edit the grub option to include `acpi=off` when booting rather than doing it in the BIOS.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting

Comment: No problem, I will create an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACPI needs to be turned off during boot.  When booting to the LiveCD, before selecting *Try Ubuntu without installing*, press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key for `Other Options` and select `acpi=off`.  Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit the `Other Options` menu, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue the boot.

For further help about selecting Other Options from a live boot, refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Answer (score 1):

Before chosing "Try ubuntu without installing" press the letter's `e` key to edit the boot option. In the longest line add `--noacpi` and press `F10`. The LiveCD will boot fine.