# lubuntu livecd sleeps/suspends on boot

Tags: boot, suspend

I have a laptop intel core 2 duo, 2GB RAM.

I'm booting from a usb flash drive using Unetbootin and lubuntu 15.10 desktop i386 version, checked MD5 correct, Tested image for errors ok.

I've tried the options "Try Lubuntu without installing" and "Install Lubuntu" and I've got this issue:

I see the splash screen and some dots and after a while my laptop goes into sleep mode. When I wake it up, the screen is blank and i see it blinking/flashing and after 30 secs it goes to sleep again. It stays like this forever. I have to hit ctrl+alt+del to restart the computer.

I've searched through the foruns and I've seen some things like doing chmod on a file, or acpi=off or vga=791 or nomodeset but I'm not sure how to do it.

On Unetbootin screen when I hit TAB, I see a command line like "> /casper/vmlinuz initrd=....quiet splash ---"

right there I've tried the options acpi=off, nomodeset, vga=791, HandleLidSwitch=ignore. Nothing worked.

I've also tried holding shift while entering any option and nothing different appeared.

Comment: Suggestion: Remove `quiet splash` options to see verbose output during the boot, then check for useful output. Edit your question to include the output seen at boot, if any.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternat install image of lubuntu [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04/release/). This image should be installable with the forcepae option. But after that you have to add the acpi=off option in grub, shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting).