# Cant boot Ubuntu 16.04 after removing laptop battery

Tags: boot, 16.04, battery

I had to remove my laptop battery as it was bloated and seemed to be a bit of a safety issue.

Since removing it I cant boot Ubuntu 16.04 any longer. I still get into Grub and can boot my Windows 10, but neither the installed version of Ubuntu nor a bootable USB stick work.

When booting from the installed version I get the following error message:

```
Ignoring BGRT: Failed to allocate memory for image
```

When booting from the USB I get:

```
INFO: Task swapper/0:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds  
Not tainted 4.4.0-21-generic #37 Ubuntu*"
```

I have a Gigabyte P34G v2. Do you guys have an idea how to fix this? (apart of getting a new battery)
Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: BGRT is the boot graphics resource table, which just has to do with the image that's displayed at boot time before the kernel gets going. That's actually a fairly innocuous issue. Is it the only error message you get when trying to boot from the hard disk?

Comment: yes it is. is it possible to just skip that?

Comment: Is the behaviour any different when you select `Advanced options for Ubuntu` > `Ubuntu, with Linux [kernel version] (recovery mode)` in the GRUB menu? Does the recovery menu appear? Does it continue to boot when you select `Resume` from that menu? Do you get to a working root shell when you select the `root` option from the recovery menu?

Comment: Is this the first time you've seen this error message? If so, then what might have happened (just a guess here) is that when you removed the battery (which is an internal one on that machine), the ACPI tables in the firmware might have been changed.

Comment: @ByteCommander tried that. i dont get into the recovery mode. i get stuck at 'clocksource: switched to clocksource tsc' and after that i get 'task kworker/u16:2:87 blocked for more than 120 seconds'

Comment: @AlcuinArundel yea thats the first time. worked well before removing the battery.

Comment: Can you try plugging the battery back in temporarily and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 2):

I too have a Gigabyte P34G v2, with a swollen battery that I have removed.
It appears that there is an ACPI bug that prevents ubuntu from booting. A work around is to turn ACPI off. Setting acpi=off in the grub boot string worked for me. More details here (plus a method to make this change permanent): [How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Comment: btw @sameer, did you notice any performances regressions? I might be wrong but it seems like my p34 is a bit more laggy

Comment: yes, ok, acpi off disable multi-core cpu, so the whole os is running with a single-core. Not a real solution unless you get a new battery quickly

Comment: @KeitIG, yeah, it wasn't ideal. However, this allowed me to continue using my laptop after sending my battery off to Gigabyte for evaluation and replacement. I was not keen on sending the whole laptop, and they agreed to send out a new battery on receipt of the swollen battery.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did, I bought a new one, will have to deal with it for a few days

Comment: Further update, as my battery has failed again, and I decided to not replace it. To have ACPI working without the battery installed, I changed the grub boot string to include acpi.power_nocheck=1 instead of acpi=off