# Is it dangerous to turn ACPI off?

Tags: acpi

I've asked a few questions related to this subject, because I could not use Ubuntu when my ACPI was alway enabled. I discovered how to install everything with ACPI off and Ubuntu is working now decently.

My question now is - is it dangerous to run Ubuntu with ACPI = off? That's the only way I can use it, at least versions like Ubuntu 14 and 16, and I want to know if using those operating systems with ACPI off would be dangerous for my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping `ACPI` off isn't necessarily dangerous. The biggest issues are:

- Power consumption
- Lifetime of certain components
- Waste heat

If you're on a laptop then I don't recommend disabling `ACPI` at all, for obvious reasons.

If you're on a desktop then there isn't an inherent danger to keeping `ACPI` off. Some components such as your SSD or CPU *may* have their lifetimes impacted, but not by noticeable amounts. Again, the biggest issues on a desktop are power consumption.

I recommend testing out disabling `ACPI`. Delete the `acpi=off` parameter from the Ubuntu kernel params at boot and see what happens (remember, editing the GRUB parameters is temporary). If you can, I advise leaving `ACPI` on.

Comment: I tried installing multiple distros with ACPI on and the only ones that work and those a little bit old, like Open Suse 13.1 or Ubuntu 12.10. On newer versions (Suse 13.2 & Ubuntu 14/16), if I don't disable ACPI everything will freeze when trying to use/install the operating system. I asked about the dangers of turning ACPI off because my Hard Drive apparently makes some noises when using Linux, noises that are absent when I'm on Windows. But it's not because of that acpi, bcause on every distro the sounds are present. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Raikuhen You're welcome, if it helped please mark it as correct :)