# ACPI Error during boot but does not cause system failure - How to fix it?

Tags: 20.04, mac

```
ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000004db
AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20210730/dswexec-431)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0.PDC due to previous error (AE_AMP_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)
/dev/sda2: clean, 325189/15294464 files, 6058136/61147904 blocks
```

I am seeing the text above during bootup on a black screen. I am using an old Macbook Air with Ubuntu 20.04. This does not cause any issues during the bootup however I am concerned with it.

Why is this coming up?

How can fix it such that I do not see this text during the bootup?

I do not want this error message to come up during every booting process. I did not install any updates after installing 20.04. The only external driver I have added is the webcam drivers.

Link to how I installed webcam drivers:https://gist.github.com/johnjeffers/3006011ec7767a4101cdd118e8d64290

I have deleted the downloaded zips and external files that are downloaded during the webcam firmware installation.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this coming up?

Miscommunication between BIOS and kernel. Kernel gets something from BIOS it does not expect. Mind that these start to show after a kernel upgrade so I would assume you did have some kind op update. Kernel 5.13 for instance introduced a couple more of those error notices but that is 22.04 not 20.04.
It could also be a security update related to the kernel.

> How can fix it such that I do not see this text during the bootup?

Fix? Upgrade BIOS if there is, also file bug reports if those are not present, and/or upgrade to a new kernel supporting your BIOS.

> I do not want this error message to come up during every booting process.

Ehm I would advice to ignore the messages. To prevent these from showing you would need to disable ACPI in grub config. Mind that this will prevent you from using the other parts of ACPI that if those currently do work (that could be things like hibernate, suspend, power modes, fan control)

See for instance [Booting Ubuntu with "acpi=off" grub parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter), [How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting), [Is it dangerous to turn ACPI off?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858370/is-it-dangerous-to-turn-acpi-off)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 fresh on Macbook Pro 2012, and then ran ubuntu-drivers manually.

The problem seems to be with kernel 6.2.0-31-generic.

The fix seems to be to push shift at boot, so that you can enter grub menu. Then select "Advanced options" and choose 5.15 -series older kernel (5.15.0-43-generic works for me).