# I just upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 but I can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, upgrade, 22.04

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 but I can't boot Ubuntu. It shows this error

[image: Error]

```
ACPI Error: Needed [Integer/String/Buffer], found [Package]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI Error during boot but does not cause system failure - How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420216/acpi-error-during-boot-but-does-not-cause-system-failure-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: It may help if you're specific with details; 20.x isn't a valid release, and even if you mean 20.04 you didn't weren't specific as to product (Server, Desktop, *flavor* etc) thus we've few clear details as to what you're actually using/asking about, nor kernel stack involved (Server & Desktop have different defaults; *flavors* can use either depending on installation media; alas you gave no details*).  Specifics allow us to be more specific in suggestions/answers.