# Ubuntu 17.04 takes 16 minutes to boot on iMAC

Tags: boot, 17.04, mac

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 on 2017 iMAC but it's taking ages to boot (16 minutes).

I've updated everything I could but the issue is still there.

I got the boot log here: https://pastebin.com/81czDnuW

It has a ton of these messages in it:

```
failed to send pre message 145 ret is 0
[  330.628585]
```

Any ideas what's causing the issue?
Thanks

Comment: That smells like a problem with ACPI. See if booting like this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting

Comment: @Rinzwind I've just tried that, but no luck :(