# Ubuntu 16.04 - Cannot reboot laptop if the lid is closed?

Tags: server, power-management, shutdown, laptop

I'm using an old laptop of mine as a media server, as such the lid is almost always closed.  There is no display other than the lid hooked up.  I have configured Ubuntu to not suspend or shut down if the lid is closed while it is booted and that works fine.  However, if I remote in and trigger a reboot then the system does not reboot properly, it just shuts down, if the lid is closed.  The lid must be open to reboot the system.  How might I change this behavior?  Ideally I'd like to be able to trigger a reboot from anywhere that I can SSH into the system from.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot directly answer your question but might be able to point you in the right direction.  ACPI is likely involved.  A quick test would be to boot without it by adding `acpi=off` to your grub kernel line.

[How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Conversely, you might need to tweak an ACPI script to make `reboot` not actually do the equivalent `shutdown -h now`

Likely also a good time to learn more about ACPI, it's actually pretty neat. 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/acpid.8.html