# Freeze installing Ubuntu 18.04 on OMEN by HP

Tags: system-installation, sound, 18.04, freeze

I bought a new OMEN Laptop by HP and I tried to install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS using a live USB Drive.
Every looked good until showed the desktop screen, in this moment the computer friezed.

Then I installed a 16.04 LTS version and work great over the half of my SSD and HD.
I Install the Nvidia drivers and works good but the sound is to low and sometimes I new to restart to make the audio comes back.
Sometimes the laptop don’t complete the shutdown sequence.

With Windows boot enabled everything is always OK.

What I what?
My goal is to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without problems.
But if you can show me how to fix my problem with Ubuntu 16.04 doesn’t be a bad idea.

This are all the Laptop specifications:

#### Computer

- Model : OMEN by HP Laptop 15-ce0xx 103C_5335KV HP OMEN
- Serial Number : 5CD73*****
- Chassis : HP Notebook
- Mainboard : HP 838F
- Serial Number : PGRLR02*******
- BIOS : AMI (OEM) F.13 01/23/2018
- TPM - Trusted Platform Module : INTC Intel 2.0 (PCR 24)
- Intel vPro : 11.6.25.1229
- Total Memory : 16GB SO-DIMM DDR4

#### Processors

- Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (4C 8T 3.81GHz, 3.5GHz IMC, 4x 256kB L2, 6MB L3)
- Socket/Slot : FC BGA1440

#### Chipset

- Memory Controller : HP Core (Kabylake-H QC) Mobile Host Bridge/DRAM Registers 100MHz, 2x 8GB SO-DIMM DDR4 2.4GHz 128-bit, Integrated Graphics

#### Memory Module(s)

- Memory Module : Samsung M471A1K43BB1-CRC 8GB SO-DIMM DDR4 PC4-19200SO DDR4-2400 (17-17-17-40 4-57-19-6)
- Memory Module : Samsung M471A1K43BB1-CRC 8GB SO-DIMM DDR4 PC4-19200SO DDR4-2400 (17-17-17-40 4-57-19-6)

#### Video System

- Monitor/Panel : ChiMei Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080, 15.5")
- Video Adapter : Intel® HD Graphics 630 (24CU 192SP SM5.2 1.1GHz, 768kB L2, 4GB DDR4 2.4GHz 128-bit, Integrated Graphics)

#### Graphics Processor

- CUDA : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (640SP 5C 1.35GHz/1.91GHz, 512kB L2, 4GB 7GHz 128-bit)
- OpenCL : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (640SP 5C 1.35GHz/1.91GHz, 80kB L2, 4GB 7GHz 128-bit)
- OpenCL : Intel® HD Graphics 630 (192SP 24C 1.1GHz, 512kB L2, 6.4GB DDR4 2.4GHz 128-bit, Integrated Graphics)
- D3D 11 : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (640SP 5C 1.35GHz/1.91GHz, 512kB L2, 4GB 7GHz 128-bit)
- D3D 11 : Intel® HD Graphics 630 (192SP 24C 1.1GHz, 768kB L2, 128MB DDR4 2.4GHz 128-bit, Integrated Graphics)
- OpenGL : GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 (4GB)

#### Storage Devices

- LITEON CA1-8D128-HP (128GB, PCIe3x4/NVMe, SED) : 119GB (C:)
- HGST HTS721010A9E630 (1TB, SATA600, 2.5", 7200rpm, 32MB Cache) : 932GB (D:) (E:)
- PCIE Card Reader (16GB, PCIe1x1/NVMe) : 15GB (F:)

#### Logical Storage Devices

- Windows (C:) : 98GB (NTFS, 4kB) @ LITEON CA1-8D128-HP (128GB, PCIe3x4/NVMe, SED)
- DATA (D:) : 454GB (NTFS, 4kB) @ HGST HTS721010A9E630 (1TB, SATA600, 2.5", 7200rpm, 32MB Cache)
- RECOVERY (E:) : 14GB (NTFS, 4kB) @ HGST HTS721010A9E630 (1TB, SATA600, 2.5", 7200rpm, 32MB Cache)
- Removable Drive (F:) : 15GB (FAT32, 32kB) @ PCIE Card Reader (16GB, PCIe1x1/NVMe)
- Hard Disk : 256MB (FAT32, 4kB) @ LITEON CA1-8D128-HP (128GB, PCIe3x4/NVMe, SED)
- Windows RE tools : 980MB (NTFS, 4kB) @ LITEON CA1-8D128-HP (128GB, PCIe3x4/NVMe, SED)

#### Peripherals

- LPC Hub Controller #1 : HP Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
- Audio Device : HP CM238 HD Audio Controller
- Disk Controller : HP Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
- Disk Controller : HP Sunrise Point-H PMC
- Disk Controller : Marvell Standard NVM Express Controller
- USB Controller #1 : HP Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
- SMBus/i2c Controller #1 : Intel ICH SMBus

#### Peripherals

- Media Player : Realtek PCIE Card Reader (14.83GB)

#### Network Services

- Network Adapter : Realtek Gaming GBE Family Controller #2 (Ethernet)
- Network Adapter : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) (Ethernet)
- Wireless Adapter : Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 (802.11n (HT), AES-CCMP, 150Mbps)

#### Power Management

- Battery #1 : HP Primary 65.05Wh/3.72Ah

#### Operating System

- Windows System : Microsoft Windows 10 Personal 10.0.16299
- Platform Compliance : x64

Comment: @capella: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We and other Stack Exchange communities are no forums but shape their communication as questions and answers. If you have a new question please [ask a new question](/questions/ask). If you want to comment on another post you can so on your own posts or on any once you earn 15 reputation points. Please don't 1) edit existing posts to talk about your your own issues (even if they're similar) or 2) abuse the answer sections for messages that don't (attempt to) answer the question at hand. I invite you to [take the tour](/tour) to learn more about or model. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer to this question but I had the same problem which I had to figure out by myself. This problem seems to stem from the fact that gaming laptops rely on nvidia graphics cards for the display and so tend to be tied to nvidia graphics drivers so there seems to be a conflict with nvidia graphics drivers and the Ubuntu noveau drivers.

The solution is to black-list the noveau drivers and install the nvidia ones .

- Disable Secure Boot (change this in BIOS)
- Go to Grub Ubuntu option (BUT DONT PRESS ENTER) Press e
  Find the line that starts with: `linux` then add: `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` after: `quiet splash`.
- After installation make sure to blacklist noveau at the installed Grub
- Then install the nvidia drivers;

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

  `sudo apt update`

  `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-[**your driver version number**]`

  `sudo reboot`

I gleaned this from a [solution](http://gist.github.com/mari-linhares/cef4cb3440408e44963d1447a7db5ae0) for MSI laptops as a guide. I had already installed Ubuntu but it was freezing at startup so at the Grub menu I just modified the Ubuntu Entry to blacklist the noveau driver and then proceeded to install nvidia drivers. **Note**: *make sure to use the correct nvidia driver for your card as it may not be the 396 used in the solution mine was 390 for the 1050Ti*

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922). In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for putting this together!

Comment: Not working for HP Omen 17, with Nvidia RTX 2080.

Comment: FYI... I faced the same problem with HP Omen - 15 ( Intel® Core™ i7-10750H, NVIDIA RTX 2070 - MAX-Q) while trying to install Ubuntu 20.04. I booted Ubuntu in safe mode and installed the NVIDIA drivers, started working for me. Did not need to blacklist the noveau drivers or disable ACPI.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with **`ACPI`** Ubuntu support.
**`ACPI`** stands for `Advanced Configuration and Power Interface`

You can bypass this by holding left shift on device turn on,
wait to see grub menu. . .

Then press key e and add acpi=off

You can see info here
http://ubuntuguide.net/turn-off-acpi-ubuntu-grub2

> **NOTE:** You will need to do this on every system start. Until you fix your drivers. Turning off permanently will affect some devices, like the **touchpad** and maybe more devices.

Better solution is to update Nvidia drivers
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

More info you can find here on link
[How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Answer (score 1):

Answer for all those owners of laptops with Ubuntu and new graphics cards:

Latest Ubuntu's releases updates and install the right driver version with a single command:

> $ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot

Enjoy!

Comment: For me it worked! A forward solution!