# Bugs during the installation of Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: grub2, nvidia, usb-installation

I tried to install several versions of Ubuntu several months ago on my laptop that is a new omen 15-dc1049nl with Nvidia gtx 1660ti, with windows 10. I tried the 18.04.3, the 19.10 and the 19.04 version of Ubuntu. The only that worked was the 19.04, I don't know why. So I have used this version until today, this morning I decided to try again the installation of 18.04, actually the 18.04.4. But again after prepared the usb pen with Rufus software I had the same following error:

[Bug during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzNYf.jpg)

What do I do wrong? Reading online I read that could be an error due to the fact that the acpi is not turned off.
Or can it be a problem of incompatibility with my pc?

Comment: First check for any firmware updates that the laptop vendor may have on their site and update BIOs/firmware.  Then google/search for acpi kernel switches, of which there are many.  acpi=off may allow you to run but in a limited fashion, until you figure out which specific switch you need. Forget 19.04, it's EOL.  Try the 20.04 beta too, it's almost ready for release and has a newer kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated the BIOS. What do you mean with 'in a limited fashion'?

Comment: acpi=off may only use one cpu core instead of all of them, so that's pretty drastic, but sometimes allows you to run when otherwise you couldn't.

Comment: ah... definitely I won't do it, I'm trying to install 20.04 right now

Comment: Did, I have the very same problem with 20.04

Comment: does no one have any suggestions?

Comment: What acpi options did you try (there are a lot)?  Did you try the modprobe.blacklist=nouveau or the nomodeset options since you have Nvidia (and may not have installed the proprietary drivers yet)?

Comment: I didn't try any apci oprtions, what I tried is to click 'e' in the installation page (Grub menu), where you can select 'install ubuntu, try ubuntu wuthout installing and so on' and then I typed 'nomodeset' before 'quiet splas' then I clicked ESC, I selected 'Try ubuntu without installing' and I got the same error

Comment: Add yourself to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1864895

Comment: I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057659/freeze-installing-ubuntu-18-04-on-omen-by-hp they seems to have the same problems