# Wired connections disconnects on high bandwith usage

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet, wired

Wired Connection on Ubuntu 18.04 keeps disconnecting every 5 min or also on high bandwith usage. I changed the cable and its still the same problem. When I use the same cable on older laptop it's working well. I found the following syslog:

```
Apr 28 20:41:42 sys-19 kernel: [   99.772408] e1000e: eno2 NIC Link is Down
```

-

```
 *-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eno2
   version: 10
   serial: 04:23:26:d3
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:123 memory:a1200000-a121ffff



lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2

Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1043:8672]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Please, help me to fix this issue. Thank you..

Comment: Looking at the info you put into your question, it looks like a cabling problem. Please describe the cabling from the computer, all the way to the router/modem. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Hi @heynnema. Thanks for your comment. I have Huawei Mobile Wifi Pro E5770 with 4G Internet and it has only one ethernet port which is connected directly to my PC. I also bought a new cable CAT6 and tried also other cables like 5, 5E but it's not working. Could be the problem because of the Internet speed ? Because when I run speedtest I get about 30 mbps ?

Comment: You marked Comar's answer as accepted. Did that fix your problem? I couldn't find any docs on the Huawei to see what speed the ethernet port is, or if there are any settings in the Huawei that can be changed.

Comment: @heynnema The speed of Huawei is about 150 Mbp/s. The wired connection does not disconnect If i run the command "sudo ethtool -s eno2 autoneg off". With nm-connection-editor I saw that Link negotiation: Ignore is by default for wired connection. When I turn on the PC or restart and run sudo lshw -c network I see that autonegotiation is on. I suppose that ethtool can't save the options that I choose by running the command.

Comment: Using nm-connection-editor, try setting link negotiation to manual/100Mb/full. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I changed the settings and now is working well. Make an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a general network problem, then this might be caused by autonegotation or/and DHCP server issues.

Try to disable autonegotation with ethtool.

Keep in mind that this might cut off network depending on your configuration.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ethtool
ethtool -s eno2 autoneg off
```

or

```
ethtool -s eno2 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off
```

Where `1000` is your NIC speed: `1000` for 1 Gpbs, or `100` for 100 Mbps.

This can also have something to do with power saving, so you may want to try disabling ACPI: [How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Comment: Thanks. I installed ethtool and when I run these commands the Ethernet Connection disconnects and I'm not able to connect again. After restart I checked with sudo lshw -c network and the speed is the same as before 100MB/S.

Comment: Only with "sudo ethtool -s eno autoneg off" the wired connection now it doesn't disconnects even on high bandwith. The only problem is that when I restart the PC and run again sudo lshw -c network I see that autonegotation is again ON.

Comment: Yeah, as I said. It's probably because your link switched to 100 Mbps, instead of 1 Gbps. The command I've written was for 1G NICs. In case of 100 Mbps you need to set it with `speed 100`, instead of `1000` or the way you did this

Answer (score 1):

In `terminal`, use the `nm-connection-editor`, set the "Link negotiation" to "manual/100Mb/full".

[image]