# Losing internet connection after a random time in 18.04 with realtek r8125

Tags: 18.04, drivers, internet

I have currently issues with my ubuntu installation, as it seems to lose internet access randomly. I have struggled to get it to work in the first place, but now I think the drivers finally stick. I usually had to reinstall the r8125 realtek drivers every reboot, but the DKMS version seems to work for a time. Then I am disconnected, and after fixing it, it works fine until next reboot.

Today, after an hour the computer lost connection to the internet. The working connection profile was used, and the only abnormal thing I noticed is that it no longer had an ip4 address shown in the settings, but was otherwise fine. I had to disable/enable the connection and then it worked. I am connected to a network where I get a dynamic IP adress, but I assume Ubuntu is capable of figuring it out itself.

What can I do to try to figure out what's going on and/or fix this?

Comment: if you are connected to the internet with lan cable, then maybe this can be helpful... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138949/wired-connections-disconnects-on-high-bandwith-usage

Comment: Thanks for the link, I checked and that connection has link negotiation on ignore already so I can see if setting it to manual will help.
Is there a log file in the system that I can use to see what is happening when I lose internet access?