# Ubuntu 19.04 trying to get DisplayLink driver to work for my adapter for usb 3.0 to hdmi

Tags: hdmi, displaylink

I just purchased a Slim USB 3.0 to HDMI® External Video Card from Starlink on amazon and I have gone through many of these before. I am trying to get it to connect to my monitor as my HDMI port has fried, but no matter how I install DisplayLink drivers, It always does not work. So I took to the internet and did some research. A lot of them just said to download the driver and then run it. Some of them mentioned running sudo apt update && sudo apt install dkms. I tried that but it did not work. then another website suggested running dmesg to see if the device is connected, but I don't know how to use it. the output is down below. But I don't know how to interpret this information. Your help is greatly appreciated.
edit:
https://pastebin.com/eh1c4wcF
edit: just tried disabling ACPI temporarily, caused two things to happen;
1. my HDMI adapter still didn't work
2. my computer began detecting the hardware that it did not have such as a hardware-enabled airplane mode switch. I don't know what ACPI does, but it did not help. 
Ok, so I just deleted and reinstalled ubuntu and installed DisplayLink under this fresh installation, and it did not work. I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eh1c4wcF

Answer (score 0):

From the Pastebin link that you mentioned I could find the error that

> ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it

So you need to disable the ACPI

For disabling that you can refer to this link
[How do I disable ACPI when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)

Comment: On a different note: for me, the nextcloud sync client appimage utterly shatters USB 3.0 displaylink functionality. It seems to make the system try and run the displaylink functionality inside the appimage.

Comment: sorry, dident work