# ACPI BIOS error when dual-booting?

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have a Dell G5 SE with an AMD GPU and CPU. I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Windows 10 from a USB drive. When I boot from the drive, the grub screen pops up and shows a few options. After a few seconds, it seems like it tries to run Ubuntu, but runs into problems.

```
ACPI BIOS error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC10.LPC0.EC0]
AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dswload2-159)
```

[image]

Comment: See if it [following these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/160056/453950) resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When booting from usb drive, the grub menu is dsplayed.
So, press "e" to enter edit mode.
Then add "acpi=off" after "quiet splash"